# How to make print use my class's __str__?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there any way to make Python's `print` use my class's `__str__`, when they are contained by other classes?

```
class C(object):
    def __str__(self):
        return 'MyC'

print C() # OK

print [C()] # prints [<__main__.C object at 0x7fb8774e59d0>]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define `__repr__` too since you're not directly calling it's `__str__` method and that printing lists calls the values' `__repr__` method not `__str__`.

```
class C(object):
    def __str__(self):
        return 'MyC'
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__() # return the same result as the __str__ method

print C() # prints MyC

print [C()] # also prints MyC
```

Answer (score 1):

Python will print the *repr*resentation when in a container, as you see. You can define the `__repr__` instead of `__str__`. However, that one is intended to produce strings that can be evaluated to get the object back again, if possible. So, to handle both of these situations in your case you can do this.

```
class C(object):
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'C()'

print( C() )

print( [C()] )
```